# how to load multiple images through keras.load_img and data augment each images for CNN model

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I want to create a CNN model to classify between 10 different cars. First, I download few images, and now I want to increase the number of images through data augmentation. Since it's hectic to do one image at a time, I have written a for loop for it, and it is showing an error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9ced4a120c2d> in <module>
     10 
     11 for i in images:
---> 12     x = img_to_array(images[i])
     13     x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
     14     j=0

~\anaconda3\envs\DSEnv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
     51 
     52     def __getitem__(self, idx):
---> 53         if idx >= len(self):
     54             raise ValueError('Asked to retrieve element {idx}, '
     55                              'but the Sequence '

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Code:

```
images = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(r'\Users\Mohda\OneDrive\Desktop\ferrari sf90 stradale')
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30, 
    width_shift_range=0.3,
    height_shift_range=0.3, 
    shear_range=0.2, 
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, 
    vertical_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

for i in images:
    x = img_to_array(images[i])
    x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
    j=0
    for batch in datagen.flow(x,batch_size=1,save_to_dir='preview',save_prefix='ferrari sf90 stradale',save_format='jpeg'):
        i+=1
        if i>20:
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to loop over the images and apply the `ImageDataGenerator` instead just use the created `ImageDataGenerator` on the path to the images and it does it on the fly for you. In order to get the images, you can call `next()` on the generator.

```
PATH_TO_IMAGES = r'\Users\Mohda\OneDrive\Desktop\ferrari sf90 stradale'

# Specify whatever augmentation methods you want to use here
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=30, 
        width_shift_range=0.3,
        height_shift_range=0.3, 
        shear_range=0.2, 
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True, 
        vertical_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        PATH_TO_IMAGES,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        save_to_dir=/tmp/img-data-gen-outputs
        class_mode='binary')

# Use the generator by calling .next()

train_generator.next()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. can you tell me how to proceed from here, how to augment each img

Comment: `train_datagen` augments all the images for you, you just have to apply it to the directory that you want with `flow_from_directory` as I did in the answer.

Comment: If you want to save the augmented images just set the path in `save_to_dir` of `flow_from_directory` as I did in the updated answer.

Comment: ok i have given the path like this `save_to_dir=r'\Users\Mohda\OneDrive\Desktop\daug'` it shows an op Found 18 images belonging to 1 classes. but i don't  see any imgs in this folder

Comment: What is the structure of the directory with the images? It needs to follow [this structure](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d#file-classifier_from_little_data_script_1-py-L17), but it does not necessarily have to be split into train, test and valid. Like this `images/train/class1/`.

Comment: a folder within a folder 'C:\Users\Mohda\OneDrive\Desktop\ferrari sf60 stradale\w'

Comment: It needs to be in the structure I linked in order to work.

Comment: So create a folder in desktop ' data' then create two sub folders one where the 'orginal image is ' and another empty folder for the ' augmented IMG '. Right

Comment: No move the images into folders based on their class names. If you have classes `one, two and three` then create those folders and move the images to their respective folders.

Comment: ok, I have 18 images of Ferrari. I renamed each image 1-18 and created folder 1-18, and put in it. I did the same for another file where the augmented data will be stored. ''' data/1-18''' this is the structure and it still didn't save the new imgs to folder

Comment: @MohamedAbdullah sorry it was my misunderstanding, it is a generator so just call `next()` on it as in the updated answer.

Comment: Hey, I have another doubt. Can u look into it and see if you can help me. here is the link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993817/getting-a-problem-during-randomsearch-while-building-a-cnn-network-logits-and`